# Decoding Base64 string to Integers in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, base64

I have a MySQL database that contains data saved as Base64 encoding. The encoded data are sequences of integers(uint8).

I would like to decode this in MySQL. I have tried using the function 'FROM_BASE64'; however, it seems to only work with encoded strings and not integers.

For clarification, the sequence of 1,0,0 is converted to 'AQAA'\

```
from 00000001 00000101 00000000\
to 000000 010000 010100 000000
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: first step, convert those uints to bytes

Comment: it will better t make this in another language than sql

Comment: can you post some base 64 strings and the result you wanted

Comment: @BerndBuffen Sure:
'AQAA' - 100
'AgIA' - 220
'AwEA' - 310
'AQIA' - 120

Comment: @EyalG - yes, but what is your desired result 1,0,0 in 3 cols  1,0,0 in 3 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have always 3 digits you can use a conv like this:

```
select CAST((FROM_BASE64('AQAA') | X'303030') AS CHAR) AS MyResult;
```

**sample**

```
mysql>  select CAST((FROM_BASE64('AQAA') | X'303030') AS CHAR)  AS MyResult;
+----------+
| MyResult |
+----------+
| 100      |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  select CAST((FROM_BASE64('AAEA') | X'303030') AS CHAR)  AS MyResult;
+----------+
| MyResult |
+----------+
| 010      |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thank you. This almost solves the problem, but it does not work when the first digit is 0 (for example - AAEA which is 010). Can you please explain the operation?

Comment: @EyalG - remove the **+ 0** from query. this will be cast from 010 to an integer

Comment: @EyalG - I have modify my answer: **select CAST((FROM_BASE64('AAEA') | X'303030') AS CHAR)  AS MyResult;**